# char pointer initialisation

Tags: c, pointers, char

why is the initialization as follows:

```
char *p = "hello";
```

allowed, but:

```
char *p = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};
```

is not, although they mean the same?

Comment: Array *is not* a pointer

Comment: try this `char *p = (char []){'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};`

Answer (score 2):

> why the initialisation as follows char *p = "hello"; is allowed.But char *p = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'}; is not allowed , although they mean the same.

Because string literals are character arrays. Arrays are not pointers (read [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=aryptr)). Both are different.

```
char *p = "hello";   // Non modifiable, store in ROM  
char p[] = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};  //Modifiable and stored in RAM
```

Comment: Read the link in question.

Answer (score 0):

The string literal `"hello"` is of type `const char *` and initializing `p` which is of type `char *` with `"hello"` is valid as an implicit conversion is invoked.

[image]

but in the second statement `{'h','e','l','l','o','\0'}` is an array of `char` and you cannot initialize a pointer with an array. To initialize `p` with an array it must be an array too:

```
char p[6] = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};
```

or

```
char p[] = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};
```

[image]

Comment: how did you draw the pictures?